# Are different OS JRE's different?

Tags: java, platform

I am questioning to myself if JRE's from different OS's (For example; Windows, Linux, Mac, etc) are all different and platform dependent? The reason I ask this is because if Java Bytecode is platform independent, that means that a JRE for a certain OS must implement the same bytecode, a bit differently specifically catered to the OS right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is platform independent because there are platform dependent compilers/interpreters for many platforms. It's platform independent in the sense that we don't have to change our code to run on a different platform, however we have to use platform specific JRE versions to run the programs.

Comment: That's pretty much the core concept around Java - the JRE is platform specific, the bytecode is not.

Comment: While bytecode is not OS-dependent, Java virtual machines are.

Comment: When programming Java for many years and getting into the corners, you find that the platform independence is not perfect. To give just one example, we are struggling these days with a bug where our Java program misbehaves on an old Linux version but behaves nicely on newer Linux as well as Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is platform dependent; although, they do run the same Java Bytecode.

Comment: Right. Essentially, the purpose of a JRE is to make it so that Java itself is platform independent (at least as much as possible).

Answer (score 2):

JRE is an acronym for Java Runtime Environment.It is used to provide runtime environment it provides JVM +libraries (which are needed by jvm), and other components to run applets and applications written in Java.

The Java Virtual machine (JVM) is the virtual machine that run the Java bytecodes. The JVM doesn't understand Java source code, that's why you compile your *.java files to obtain *.class files that contain the bytecodes understandable by the JVM. so you write your code once (generate .class files) and run it on diffrent JVMs. There are specific implementations of the JVM for different systems (Windows, Linux..). JVM dose theses tasks Loading classes, Verifying code, Executin code and Providing runtime environment.

There is also another term called JDK which consist of JRE + development tools.

Answer (score 1):

The JREs are both platform and architecture-specific, but the bytecode and JVM function identically between all platforms (there is still a difference between architectures x86 and x64)